# Replace values in element in xml file using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to remove unnecessary text inside values in elements in xml file and I want use an XSLT transformation to do that.

In this example file i want to remove specific tags like `<br>`, `<prefix>`, `<suffix>` inside value of `<Value>` elements.

There will be many `<Product>` elements. And I don't want change structure of this file, so this should be like copy, but with with logic to remove specific texts.

I tried to use templates and copy, but somehow I cannot connect them together.

If any of you could help me with or give me hints that I should follow, I would appreciate.

```
<ProductInfo>
  <Products>
    <Product>
     <Name>xyz</Name>
     <Values>
        <Value><br/>test</Value> <-- remove <br/>
        <Value><prefix/>test2</Value> <-- remove <prefix>
        <Value><suffix/>test3</Value> <-- remove <suffix/>
     </Values>
    </Product>
  <Product>
     <Name>xyz</Name>
     <Values>
        <Value><br/>test</Value> <-- remove <br/>
        <Value><prefix/>test2</Value> <-- remove <prefix/>
        <Value><suffix/>test3</Value> <-- remove <suffix/>
     </Values>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</ProductInfo>
```

Output file should look like:

```
<ProductInfo>
  <Products>
    <Product>
     <Name>xyz</Name>
     <Values>
        <Value>test</Value>
        <Value>test2</Value>
        <Value>test3</Value>
     </Values>
    </Product>
  <Product>
     <Name>xyz</Name>
     <Values>
        <Value>test</Value> 
        <Value>test2</Value> 
        <Value>test3</Value> 
     </Values>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</ProductInfo>
```

Comment: Will all those "tags" that you wish to remove be empty as in the given example? Or could you have e.g. `<Value>Some <b>important</b> text.</Value>`?

Comment: Yes probably this case could happen.

Comment: So what should the result be then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Value">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will remove any markup contained in a `Value` element by returning only it [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) - i.e. *"the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order"*.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would it be possible to replace them into other characters rather then removing them ?

Comment: You need to edit your question and explain in detail what should be replaced with what. Or - perhaps preferably - post a new question, since this one already has two answers that meet the originally stated requirement.

Comment: P.S. Note that those "tags" you refer to are actually *elements*. They can be replaced by text, but they themselves are not "characters".

Comment: You shouldn't have. I have rolled it back to what it was when @MadsHansen and I answered it. Please post a new question with your new requirement.

Comment: I created new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77067827/manipulate-values-in-element-in-xml-file-using-xslt

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with an [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) with additional empty template(s) matching the content that you want to drop/remove.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">      
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!--empty template matching the elements that we want to drop and not appear in the result-->
    <xsl:template match="Value/br | Value/prefix | Value/suffix"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could have separate empty match templates for each of those match patterns instead of using the `|` union.

Also, if you wanted to remove all elements that appear inside of the `Value` elements, you could match more generically with `Value/*`.

Comment: Thank you very much, but how it happend that those prefix, suffix are removed ? And would it be possible to replace them to other character rather then removing them ?

Comment: You should read up on the identity template, and "push style" https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/07/06/tr.html to understand how things work. Essentially, when a template matches, what is defined within the template decides what to do (sort of like a choose your own adventure book). If it's an empty template, it does nothing. If it matches the default template that copies that node and then "pushes" the attributes and child nodes - the processor will look to see which templates match those items.

Comment: It could match the default template, which will simply copy and push again, or it could match that empty template that removes it by doing nothing. If you want to match `<br/>` and change it to something else, create a template that matches it and then do whatever you want.